# Spring boot JPA ddl-auto update

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

When i try to set ddl auto to update, every time I run the application, it shows that hibernate tries to create the tables again. I am trying to add another column in the database using the entity

```
@Column(name = "xref_reason", length = 20)
private String xRefReason;
```

Shouldn't it creates this column only that I added?

Here is the error.

```
Hibernate: create table tbcodetable (id bigint identity not null, codename varchar(255), codevalue varchar(255), desc1 varchar(255), desc2 varchar(255), primary key (id))2018-06-26 16:23:09.342  WARN 4284 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: There is already an object named 'tbcodetable' in the database.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1535) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:845) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:752) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:219) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:199) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.execute(SQLServerStatement.java:729) ~[mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 119 common frames omitted
```

even the foreign keys has the same error.

application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=dbname
    username: user
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      pool-name: collectionPool
      auto-commit: false

  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      default_schema: dbo
      ddl-auto: update
      naming:
        physical-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
        implicit-strategy: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

Comment: Hi @Cedric please change ddl-auto:none  to ddl-auto: update  and update your project.

Comment: Hi Sir, Sorry, I pasted it wrong it was ddlq-auto: update when I recieve the error.

Comment: your issue is solve??

Comment: Not yet Sir. Its still the same.